# Is this the correct way to play repeating alarm tone?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-alarms

I am making an Alarm app. I need to play user selected tone which I set through `RingtoneManager`.
When an alarm goes off, this is how I play the alarm tone:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Uri alarmSound = prefs.getString("alarmSound", ""); //alarmSound is the Uri of alarm tone
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(NormalAlarm.this, alarmSound);
try 
{
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
} 
catch (IllegalStateException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It works fine but the volume which it uses is of course the `Media Volume` of the phone. How do I make it work with `Alarm Volume` of the phone ?
I am using `MediaPlayer` since I want the alarm tone to repeat until the user stops the alarm.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

[MediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType%28int%29) is what you're looking for:

```
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
mp.setLooping(true);
mp.start();
```

Comment: Its still playing on `Media Volume`.

Comment: Does your app request the `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission? You may also need to call mp.prepare() after you call mp.setAudioStreamType(). Please update your code if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check the permissions and try the prepare() suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I added that permission and called prepare() after setting the audio stream type.

Comment: Strange. You might try [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536391/how-to-correctly-set-mediaplayer-audio-stream-type), which uses `mp = new MediaPlayer()` and `mp.setDataSource()` instead of `MediaPlayer.create()`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using `MediaPlayer.create()` to create your MediaPlayer. `Create` function calls the `prepare()` function which finalize your media and does not allow you to change `AudioStreamType`.

The solution is using `setDataSource` instead of create():

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
mp.setLooping(true);
try {
   mp.setDataSource(NormalAlarm.this, alarmSound);
   mp.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
mp.start();
```

See [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20int)) for more information.