# MediaPlayer.start() not play sounds in s3

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I added in my app a simple feature that plays a simple sound when the button is clicked. It works fine with my Nexus 7 AVD, but when i run the code in Galaxy s3, it not displays any sound. The code is:

`private void turnOnFlash() {`

```
    if(!isFlashOn) {
        if(camera == null || parameters == null) {
            return;
        }
    }

    this.playSound();
    parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();
    isFlashOn = true;
}
```

and the playSound method:

`private void playSound() {`

```
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bar);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
    mediaPlayer.start(); //working on AVD, but do not work in S3.
}
```

Can someone help me fix this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding the MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission to your manifest? Alternatively try setting a different Audio Stream type.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3539494/833647

Comment: For simple sound playback, you might be better off with SoundPool (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the device sets the media volume to zero, 
You can set media volume programmatically using this snippet of code :

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
```

This should help..