# MediaPlayer sound not always playing, not getting granted audio focus

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm having an issue with some android code to play a sound notification on certain events.

Here's the code:

```
int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(MainRunningService.afChangeListener,AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);


if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
   mp = new MediaPlayer();
   mp.setDataSource(context, soundToPlay);
   mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
   mp.prepare();

   mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            try {
                                Log.d(LOGTAG, "SoundService MUSIC: MUSIC IS NOW COMPLETE");
                                mp.release();
                                mp = null;
                                Log.d(LOGTAG, "SoundService MUSIC: MUSIC IS NOW COMPLETE - RELEASED");
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                       });
   mp.setLooping(false);
   mp.start();                         
}
else{
   Log.w(LOGTAG, "SoundService Audiofocus was not granted");
}
```

What I'm finding is that sometimes it will play, whereas other times it won't play. When it doesn't play it's hitting the "SoundSerice Audiofocus was not granted" log line. I've looked at the system logs, but can't find anything that says why it's not been granted.

Once this has happened, then every request seems to fail.

Does anyone have any pointers to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Try a different stream type to test or add MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission to your manifest. Seemed to help here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3539494/833647

Comment: Another app could just be not letting go of the focus.  But I notice there is no call to give up the audio focus ever.  That could be a problem.  The call is abandonAudioFocus, put it in your completion listener.

Comment: are you looking for some code that plays an audio file (MediaPlayer) coding?

Comment: @gabe abandonAudioFocus is getting called when releasing the media player. It was in another method of the app that I'd not included - it runs: audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(MainRunningService.afChangeListener);

Comment: @TharakaNirmana some sample code may be handy

Comment: I will post as an answer below:

Answer (score 0):

//call the method playAssistClip() on button click or wherever you want.

```
private MediaPlayer mp;
    private void playAssistClip() {
            if (workoutReps.equalsIgnoreCase("6x6x6")) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(ProcessWorkout.this,
                        R.raw.six_six_six_formated_ogg);
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    //do something after the audi ends
                        mp.reset();
                        mp.release();
                        finish();
                    }

                });
                mp.start();
               //to get the duration of clip
                spentTimeOnWorkout = mp.getDuration();

            }
```

Comment: I see you've got no references to requesting audio focus or releasing it. Shouldn't that be included?