# Alarm sound is not identified as alarm type

Tags: android, alarm

I am creating an alarm for android. The problem is that the alarm sound is not identified as alarm type.
A link to the photo to see what i want.
[Sound types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XqyH.png)

This is the code I'm using to set the tone and play .

```
       Uri alarmTone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
       Ringtone ringtoneAlarm = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), alarmTone);
```

For play the alarm.

```
      ringtoneAlarm.play();
```

How do you solve this?

Comment: per your description, you are trying to get alarm icon, right?

Comment: No. I'm trying to get the sound to play , but in the type of alarms. I am specifying alarm type , but played in the type of notifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching I found the solution based on this link.

[How to correctly set MediaPlayer audio stream type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536391/how-to-correctly-set-mediaplayer-audio-stream-type)

I have adapted the code to play the alarm.

```
am=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
    mp=new MediaPlayer();
    alarmTone=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    try
    {
        mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), alarmTone);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //exception caught in the end zone
    }
```

I've also added this permission to manifest file.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

Now works perfect!!

Answer (score 1):

I have just create example with HTC Sensation Android 4.0.3(API 15). Please download [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4E1qxhiuLQ6dHMyX2d1MUluZ0k/view?usp=sharing) 
Please check again your setup RingTone on your device. if you still have problem, please share your project, I can assist you to figure out the problem.